# Java: HashMap.getOrDefault returns null value

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception

I'm fairly new to **Java** coming from a **Python** and **C#** background. I don't know why I am getting a `null` value for `HashMap.getOrDefault()` when from my understanding, this method is built in the first place to avoid NullPointer exceptions. The `people` object is not null, neither is `idKey`.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the NPE

Comment: The hashmap probably explicitly has `null` associated for that key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `getOrDefault()` will return the default value *when the key is not found*, as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).
If the key is found but the value is `null`, then `null` will be returned.

So, it seems that your map actually contains the key but the corresponding value is null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the key is not in the HashMap. Sorry, I didn't mention this in the question. I will edit it and add this as well.

Comment: Please include the code modifying the `people` map. Could there be a concurrency issue (i.e. map entries being added/removed by multiple threads)?

Comment: Checked, thanks for pointing it out! Accepted as answer.

Answer (score 4):

As @TasosP already mentioned, your map most likely contains a `null` value. You could deal with it as follows:

```java
int itemId = Optional.ofNullable(people.get(idKey))
                     .map(Object::toString)
                     .map(Integer::parseInt)
                     .orElse(0);
```

The code snippet above will handle both missing and `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap.getOrDefault()` returns the value to which the key is mapped and default value if there is no mapping. In your case, the only explanation is that `idKey` is present in `people` and mapped to `null`.

The following code returns `null`:

```
java.util.Map<String, String> map = new java.util.HashMap<>();
map.put("foo", null);
return map.getOrDefault("foo", "bar");
```

You get `bar` if you remove the `put` call.